# Ajax Json request not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

So I'm juste trying to create a counter which update a value in my database everytime I click on a button and then I would like to display this value on the page. My code to update the value is working, but my code to display the value doesn't want to work.

Here is my js code to refresh the counter :

```
<script>
setInterval("checkCount()",500); 
function checkCount()
{
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'http://ntc.aiesecfrance.org/server_count_get/',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
           alert("data.count");       
        }
    });
};
</script>
```

and here is my php code to get the value from the database.

```
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "test", "", "test");
  if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
      echo 'connection failed';
  }
// Fetching the value
$query  = "SELECT count FROM counterval WHERE id=1";
$count = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
$value = mysqli_fetch_array($count);

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($value);
?>
```

but with this I got no alert. It just doesn't show up.
Here is an example of what is retunrned by the php :

`{"0":"8","count":"8"}`

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Do some basic debugging. Look at your browser's developer tools. Look at the Console. Does it show any errors? Look at the Net tab. Does it show the request being made? To the right URL? Do you get the response you expect?

Answer (score 2):

You have to remove the quotes.

It will be:

`alert(data.count)`

EDIT

Try this.

```
jQuery.get('http://ntc.aiesecfrance.org/server_count_get/', function(r) {
    var json = $.parseJSON(r);
    alert(json.count);  
});
```

I hope you included jQuery. Anyway, try also to put the function inside

```
$(function() {
   function checkCount() { ... }
});
```

**EDIT 2 (IMPORTANT)**

I saw that the output is an HTML page, not only the JSON. Try this.

```
$.get('http://ntc.aiesecfrance.org/server_count_get/', function(r) {
        var $html = $(r);
        var json_value = $html.find('#post-291 .entry-content').text();
        var json = $.parseJSON(json_value);
        alert(json.count);  
    });
```

*Anyway you **can't** do cross-origin calls.*

Comment: Yeah sorry it was just to test. But it still doesn't work

Comment: I edited the answer. Check it! PS: It's POST or GET method?

Comment: "Anyway you can't do cross-origin calls." — That isn't true. We have CORS, JSONP and Proxies which make cross-origin calls possible.

Comment: Hello, I tried what you said, and it's not working, jQuery is enabled because I'm using it to increase the value and it is working. Now I have this in the console : ReferenceError: checkCount is not defined
But I think it appeared because I putted the function inside.

Comment: Can you put it in jsbin o something like that?

Comment: https://jsbin.com/waqofi/edit?html,js,console Here it is, but thinking about what you said, I think that the best solution would actually be to find a way to have a better php output, not in a html file, but just a Json

Answer (score 0):

I finnaly manage to do it, In fact this jQuery code was good :

```
<script>
setInterval("checkCount()",500); 
function checkCount()
{
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'http://ntc.aiesecfrance.org/get_count/',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
           alert(data.count);       
        }
    });
};
</script>
```

The only probleme was the plugin of wordpress I was using which was runing the php and displaying it into the main page. But then the answer was way more than json (html containing json) and this is why it didn't worked. But now it's fully working so thanks again for your help :)

Answer (score -1):

Your `setInterval` call is broken. You want `setInterval(checkCount, 500)` rather than `setInterval("checkCount()", 500)`. The latter is passing a string, and even without the quotes it'd be calling the function and passing its return value; `setInterval` takes the function itself.

Comment: `setInterval` can take either a function or a string to be evaluated. Passing a function is best practise, but it won't solve the problem here. "even without the quotes " — Removing the quotes without removing the () would cause that problem, but nobody is suggesting doing that.